# when this exception occurs?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to und
lying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: 

connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0

(Native Method)
        at 

java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect

(DualStackPlainSocke
mpl.java:69)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect

(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.
va:316)
        at 

java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress

(AbstractPlainSock
Impl.java:177)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect

(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
:164)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect

(PlainSocketImpl.java:154)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect

(SocksSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:578)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:424)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:240)
        at 

com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect

(StandardSocketFactory.
va:173)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>

(MysqlIO.java:268)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO

(Connection.java:2745)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>

(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect

(NonRegisteringDriver.ja
:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

(DriverManager.java:620)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

(DriverManager.java:200)
        at Database.Connectivity.<init>

(Connectivity.java:48)
        at Form.SignIn.<init>(SignIn.java:64)
        at Form.SignIn$5.run(SignIn.java:389)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch

(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent

(EventQueue.java:649)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters

(EventDispatchTh
ad.java:255)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter

(EventDispatchThrea
java:170)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy

(EventDispatchTh
ad.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents

(EventDispatchThread.java:15

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents

(EventDispatchThread.java:14

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run

(EventDispatchThread.java:136)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO

(Connection.java:2820)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>

(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect

(NonRegisteringDriver.ja
:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

(DriverManager.java:620)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

(DriverManager.java:200)
        at Database.Connectivity.<init>

(Connectivity.java:48)
        at Form.SignIn.<init>(SignIn.java:64)
        at Form.SignIn$5.run(SignIn.java:389)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch

(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent

(EventQueue.java:649)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters

(EventDispatchTh
ad.java:255)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter

(    EventDispatchThrea
java:170)
        at 

java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy

(EventDispatchTh
ad.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents

(EventDispatchThread.java:15

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents

(EventDispatchThread.java:14

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run

(EventDispatchThread.java:136)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if

- MySQL server is too busy or hung
- Network unreachable
- MySQL server is not started
- connection parameters used are not valid. (host/port)

Check if you can telnet to the host port of mysql server from the server/machine you are executing this code. If the host and port are valid and the connection is fine, then telnet will show a blank screen. Otherwise it would show something like

> Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

Answer (score 1):

A `ConnectionException` with message `"connection timed out"` could occur if:

- the MySQL service is catatonic / hung,
- the MySQL service is running but is too busy to accept new connections,
- a firewall is "black holing" connection attempts, or
- a networking hardware or routing problem is "black holing" connection attempts.

There are other reasons for connection failures, but they will result in different exceptions or different messages.  (For instance, you could see "connection refused", "unknown host", "host unreachable", "network unreachable" ...)